# Does anyone have any tips on how to solve this Codewars Kata to find squares from rectangle?

Tags: python

I am doing the code wars rectangular into squares Kata. I am very new to python, just trying to learn.

The aim is to split a given length and width into squares:
https://www.codewars.com/kata/55466989aeecab5aac00003e/train/python

This is what I have so far. I cannot figure out how to determine whether the square will fit in the rectangle. Any tips will be appreciated.

```
def sqInRect(lng, wdth):
    solution = []
    b =  (lng * wdth) - (wdth**2)
    solution.append(wdth)
    print(b)
    if lng == wdth:
        return None
    else:
        for i in range(wdth,0,-1):
            print("i is " + str(i))
            if b - (i**2) > 0:
                if wdth + i <= lng:
                    solution.append(i)
                    b = b- i**2
                    print("Yes!")
                    print(b)
                    if b-(i**2) >= 0:
                        solution.append(i)
                        b = b - (i**2)
                        print("DOne")
                        print(b)
        
        
    return solution
```

Comment: Do it the way you would do it as a human being.  The largest square you can take is the minimum of the height and width.  You remove that from the rectangle and repeat.  So, given 5x3, you take a 3x3 and you're left with 2x3.  From that, you can take a 2x2 and you're left with 2x1.  That decomposes into two 1x1.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it methodically, step by step.

```
def sqInRect(length, width):
    sizes = []
    while length and width:
        side = min(length,width)
        sizes.append(side)
        print( "%dx%d" % (side,side) )
        if length == side:
            width -= side
        else:
            length -= side
    return sizes

print(sqInRect(5,3))
```